# Mapping XML attributes/elements with Table Column Names for File Import

Tags: xml, import, mapping

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ProdExtract>
 <ExtractHeader>
  <Schema>
   <id>Accord ePOS Product Extract</id>
   <Version>1.00</Version>
  </Schema>  
 </ExtractHeader>
 <Product>
  <Mode>Modify</Mode>
  <ProductID>  
    <LongDescription>COLMANS MINT SAUCE      #</LongDescription>  
  </ProductID>
  <BasicFields>  
    <Units>6</Units>
    <VAT VatCode="A" VatRate="0" />  
  </BasicFields>
  <Price>  
    <CurrentWSP>9.55</CurrentWSP>
    <CurrentRSP>2.01</CurrentRSP>  
  </Price>
  <Barcode>  
    <Eancode>5000147032921</Eancode>  
  </Barcode>
 </Product>
</ProdExtract>
```

This is my mapping for the table columns

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("ProdExtract/Product"))                    
{                     
    insert = insert ?? new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<ProductViewModel>("public", "q_product")
        .MapUUID("q_guid", x => Guid.NewGuid())
        .MapText("q_description", x => node.SelectSingleNode("ProductID/LongDescription").InnerText)
        .MapText("q_barcode", x => node.SelectSingleNode("Barcode/Eancode").InnerText)
        .MapNumeric("q_casesize", x => Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("BasicFields/Units").InnerText))
        .MapNumeric("q_sellprice", x => Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("Price/CurrentRSP").InnerText))
        .MapNumeric("q_casecost", x => Convert.ToDecimal(node.SelectSingleNode("Price/CurrentWSP").InnerText))
                        ;

    entities.Add(p);                        
}
```

I can get all the values I need from the XML file and match them with my table columns no problemo, with the above method. But now how do I deal with with this section

```
<BasicFields>  
  <Units>6</Units>
  <VAT VatCode="A" VatRate="0" />  
</BasicFields>
```

If I want the value of VatRate i.e 0. This line

```
node.SelectSingleNode("BasicFields/Vat/VatRate").OuterXml;
```

[image: debugging]

brought me nowhere, and I have had no luck on the interwebs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured it out (This is in c# code by the way, I havent checked if its any different in other languages)

```
<BasicFields>  
 <Units>6</Units>
 <VAT VatCode="A" VatRate="0" />  
</BasicFields>
```

To get value "A"

```
node.SelectSingleNode("BasicFields/VAT").Attributes["VatCode"].Value;
```

To get value "0"

```
node.SelectSingleNode("BasicFields/VAT").Attributes["VatRate"].Value;
```